# Symfony2 transfer counters in referenced Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I've encountered a problem while trying to fetch some information that I thought should be there between related entities in Symfony2 with Doctrine.

Let's say I have an entity called "Publisher" which haves many "Magazines" which have many "Chapters" which have many "Pages", and I want to fetch, from one "Publisher" object get the total amount of Pages that all their Magazines, through chapters, have.

Whil trying to count the Magazines, directly related, I have no problem (I'm using Twig as template).
In the controller i retrieve the list:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Publisher')->findAll();
```

And in the view I can render this:

```
{{ entity.magazines.count }}
```

Which gives me the Magazines related to that publisher. But when i try to do the following:

```
{{ entity.magazines.chapters.count }}
```

(Assuming "Chapters" is another entity related ManyToOne Magazine) it throws an error.
I know I'm missing something here but I cannot figure out what it is. Could someone help me or give a tip on how to do this?

Comment: "Method "issues" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in C:\..."
But in the "Magazines" object there is (or should be) the "Issues" method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in this way. You should use the DQL instead.

At now after accessing `entity.magazines` you get a Collection of Magazine Entities and you should loop this collection to access the `chapters` of the each items in the `entity.magazines` collection

So see the `Using Aggregate Functions` [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)